# Css - Wrap text around image then reposition at break point

Tags: html, css, text

I have a little tricky responsive css problem.

I'm creating articles where there is a body of text on the left, and an image on the right. And the text wraps around the image. Then on the break point I need the body copy to be above the image.

When i use this code:

```
<section class="news-article-body">
    <img src="img/news-article-image.jpg" alt="" title=""/>
    <p> 
      Lorem Ipsum...
    </p>
</section
```

Css:

```
.news-article-body img {
    float: right;
}
```

Looks great. Image floats right and the text wraps around when needed.
But because the image tag is before the copy I cant get the image below the copy at the break point.

So basically I need the text to wrap with this html (Or another solution):

```
<section class="news-article-body">
    <p> 
      Lorem Ipsum...
    </p>
    <img src="img/news-article-image.jpg" alt="" title=""/>
</section
```

Anyone know of a technique for this? I couldnt seem to figure it out.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use display:flex and order :

at break point it would be from your piece of HTML :

```
.news-article-body {
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
}
.news-article-body img {
order:2;
}
```

---

Javascript and float clearing can help too : **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ecKlk/?editors=101)** or **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DfpnL/)**

Code example :

```
onload=function() {
  document.getElementById('myImg').style.position='absolute';// take img out of the flow
  var myoffsetHeight = document.getElementById('myP').offsetHeight;//return height of <p>
  document.getElementById('myT').style.height=myoffsetHeight +'px'; //set height to floatting element
  document.getElementById('myImg').style.position='static';//bring img back in the flow
}
```

from a structure like this :

```
<section >
  <b id="myT"></b>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/100/" id="myImg"/>
<p id="myP">Pellentesque ....</p>
</section>
```

---

in both example, do not forget set your breakpoint

Comment: good solution. But i need it to work for IE9 and up and i dont think flex or order are supported

Comment: does <p> has a known height ?

Comment: The <p> will have a different amount of text in it everytime. Though there could be multiple <p> tags

Comment: okay, the idea was , http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ecKlk/ , you may need then to use javascript to retrieve height of paragraph and and apply it to that floatting pseudo element wich image will clear from

Comment: @DustinSilk ?? anyone here .. so with js , it goes this way : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ecKlk/?editors=001

Comment: Awesome thanks, works perfectly. I'll put it in a window.resize event to continually update when needed

Comment: okay, glad this helped you find a way, keepd the flex CSS, the float can be a fallback for older browser

Comment: @DustinSilk flex + javaScript as fallback : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ecKlk/?editors=111

Answer (score 0):

Simply insert an `<img>` tag at the beginning of your article text and use `align="right"` to get the text to wrap around it.

Comment: Already have it wrapping using a float. At the responsive breakpoint i then need the text to position above the image. thats the problem

Comment: are you comfortable using jQuery?

Comment: I was hoping to have a pure CSS solution. GCyrillus (below) had a great solution but IE9 doesnt support it, theres a few ways to go about it with javascipt. i'll use his reference to this post: codepen.io/anon/pen/ecKlk. works perfectly. uses more css over jQuery and doesnt rearrange the DOM.